# Does the IIS 7.5 has any anti-dos or anti-flood mechanism built in and enabled by default?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis, socket

Inside my windows 2008 R2 I am running a secure websocket server (XSockets.NET). When there are too many connections to the server, the server just stops responding at all. The developers claim, that they tested their server software, and it should be working fine.

The weird thing about this is, that when I make like, 1000 connections to this server at once, and it will break, it will remain broken even after I restarted it! So I am starting to think, that maybe windows itself is blocking those connections? Because why else wouldn't it work after a restart? It seems like there is some kind of a cooldown that needs to pass in order to get that service back again.

So, my question is: is there *anything* in windows server 2008 r2 (or IIS itself), that could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in IIS 7.5, the [default application pool *queue length*](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/applicationpooldefaults) is exactly 1000 requests. When the number of requests in the application pool's queue reaches this limit, HTTP.sys will start responding to requests with `HTTP 503.3`.

You can modify this value per application pool:

- Open IIS Manager (`inetmgr`)
- Navigate to Application Pools
- Right-click an Application Pool -> Advanced Properties or select "Set Application Pool Defaults"
- Change the property named "Queue Length"